# Missing PDO in a CAN bus of SocketCAN on a linux CPU board

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, can-bus, socketcan

It is being observed that multiple PDO go missing when a CPU has high usage and also when there is a high traffic via SSH connection. The arrangement is such that SocketCAN api of the linux system is used to create a CAN BUS containing 3 devices.When observing the candump command, it is seen that multiple PDO as well as frame are dropped. Below is a snapshot of the candump when a PDO missing occured.

```
/candump can0 -t A -x -d -e
```

```
(2021-02-10 16:58:40.464701)  can0  RX - -  481   [4]  00 00 00 00
 DROPCOUNT: dropped 280 CAN frames on 'can0' socket (total drops 66531)
```

System specification: 4 core processors, 1 GB RAM,40GB space.
Device statistic during stress test: CPU usage: 90% , temperature: 80°c
The endurance test was carried by running a bash script from a server PC which create SSH connection, uploads and downloads file of size 450Mb in a loop. The main idea was to see what happens to CAN frame during such stress situation.

Does anyone have an insight or idea regarding such issue, or any suggestion to a solution for such issue. Thank you in advance for the time and patience.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also show the `candump` command that you use. Your application might be too slow to process the CAN frames in time. Does your application use filtering to reduce the number of messages received from the driver?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The application does not use any filter to reduce the number of messages received. This is observed only when the stress on ssh traffic or cpu is high

Comment: Please add all clarification or requested information **to the question** instead using comments to answer. It is clear that high load may slow down your application. Are there any messages that are not needed for your application and could be filtered out?

Comment: Linux isn't a real-time OS, what did you expect. You need to use some device with enough hardware buffers to store messages until the OS decides to grace your process with its presence.

Comment: Not enough info. How many cores? How much traffic?  Have you measured idle time? Are you disabling interrupts?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question. No interrupts where disabled